Remove spaces from a substring within a string using Regex.Replace and a wildcard
I am playing around with sending strings to Google Translate. The strings I am using contain {0} tags that are used for formating string.format commands.
Turns out that Google translate does not handle these tags for all languages. After some experimentation, I have found that I can replace "{0}" with "|{0}|" and swap them back after the translate. This so far is the only combination to work for all languages... except that some languages seem to return the "|{0}|" with spaces such as "| {0} |".
I am looking for a Regex.Replace command to remove spaces within a string but only for said tags.
For example, the string
Hi |{0}| from |{1}|, how are you today?
will return for French:

Bonjour |{0}| de |{1}|, comment allez-vous aujourd'hui ?

and for Uyghur:

ئەسسالامۇئەلەيكۇم | {0} | دىن | {1} | ، بۈگۈن قانداقراق؟

The Regex.Replace statement will have to use a wildcard suitable for any number, some being double digit. Once the spaces have been removed, I can swap back programically the text they are in place of (not always a tag).
EDIT:
Yes sorry, this is another "Give me a regex that does X" question. I would be quite happy for a link to a post explaining how to separate out the substrings within a main string for a Regex command to work on. There are plenty of examples of Regex commands out there, but they all seem to effect the WHOLE string, not just a given section of it.
There are other options available to me... I could simply (and will probably end up doing) just make another check for the substring complete with spaces. I was hoping for a more elegant solution!

Questions that ask "Give me a regex that does X" with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

This doesn't seem like a robust approach to internalization. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j74jcxSunY, specifically around 1:28.

@gunr2171 Everything I have seen and researched seems to remove ALL spaces, not just the spaces within a substring.

@gunr2171 Thanks for the video. Yes sending to Google is not a perfect system - I know that. But at least for the time being, it is what I am doing.

Regex Pattern
Here’s the regex used:
(\|)\s*(\{)\s*(\d+)\s*(\})\s*(\|)

Breakdown

(\|): Captures the pipe character |. This is the first group ($1).
\s*: Matches zero or more spaces.
(\{): Captures the opening curly brace {. This is the second group ($2).
(\d+): Matches one or more digits (the number inside the tag), captured as the third group ($3).
(\}): Captures the closing curly brace }. This is the fourth group ($4).
(\|): Captures the closing pipe character |. This is the fifth group ($5).

Why Use Groups?
The capturing groups let us keep the parts we want (like |, {, }) while removing any spaces in between using the Regex.Replace method.
Replacement String
"$1$2$3$4$5"

This uses back-references to the captured groups:

$1: First group (opening |)
$2: Second group (opening {)
$3: Third group (the digits)
$4: Fourth group (closing })
$5: Fifth group (closing |)

This removes the spaces but keeps the placeholder structure intact.
A test code:
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Original translated string with spaces around placeholders
        string input = "Hi | {0} | from | {1} |, how are you today?";

        // Regex pattern using groups to capture parts of the placeholder
        string pattern = @"(\|)\s*(\{)\s*(\d+)\s*(\})\s*(\|)";

        // Replace method using back-references to reassemble the match without spaces
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1$2$3$4$5");

        // Output the result
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}


Thankyou kindly for your answer. I think it was the grouping and $1 bit needed help with. I was just coming back to post a something similar after finally piecing it all together:     string newString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(|)[ ]({[0-9]+})[ ](|)", "$1$2$3"); Your detailed explaination is fantastic and from what I have seen is the best explaination I have seen to date - all the information, all in one place.

Also for anyone else, like me, needing help, I found this site rather useful... https://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Thanks for the nice words @damichab :)
And for the link.
By the way, this one is cool to keep trained https://regexcrossword.com/

Here is a web site that is great for seeing the content of your matches like groups, named groups. Even like substitution using the back reference $1, $1, ... to reformat the text : https://regex101.com.
Finally, you can use substitution with Notepad++, Geany and VSCode directly. Sometimes it's faster than coding.

That website is really good - better than the one I found.
